Apach Spark MongoDB Connection Null Pointer Exception Error
I encountered a java.lang.NullPointerException error while attempting to connect to MongoDB via Apache Spark using the MongoDB Spark Connector. The connection could not be established."
I have attempted various solutions, including downgrading my JDK to version 11 and using a compatible MongoDB Spark driver. However, I am still encountering the same error.
This is my code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# MongoDB connection parameters
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/service_code"

# Create Spark session with MongoDB connector
print("Creating Spark session...")
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MongoDBConnection") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", MONGO_URI) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", MONGO_URI) \
    .config("spark.jars", "/Users/rds/PycharmProjects/HelloSpark/venv/libs/mongo-spark-connector_2.13-10.3.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
print("Spark session created.")

# Get list of collections
collections = spark.sparkContext._jvm.com.mongodb.MongoClient(MONGO_URI).listDatabaseNames()

# Convert Java list to Python list and print
print("Collections in the database:")
for collection in collections.iterator():
    print(collection)

# Stop the Spark session
print("Stopping Spark session...")
spark.stop()
print("Spark session stopped.")

I  am encountering the same error while running it on PyCharm IDE, and running it on the shell also produced the same error.
Below is the error I am getting
24/06/03 18:30:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/06/03 18:30:35 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$register(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
24/06/03 18:30:35 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater

https://i.sstatic.net/FXwNm0Vo.png
